# How to Ignore Whitespaces using preg_match()

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
">ANY CONTENT</span>(<a id="show
```

I need to fetch ANY CONTENT. However, there are spaces in between

```
</span> and (<a id="show
```

Here is my preg_match:

```
$success = preg_match('#">(.*?)</span>\s*\(<a id="show#s', $basicPage, $content);
```

\s* represents spaces. I get an empty array!

Any idea how to fetch CONTENT?

Comment: Works fine for me, `$content[1]` returns `ANY CONTENT`

Comment: @scibuff This i just a quick temporary rough code...

Comment: @anubhava Right, but it fetches rest of page. I just need to fetch what's between </span> and (<a id="show, not beyond (<a id="show...

Comment: Do you need to fetch `ANY CONTENT`, `CONTENT` or what comes after </span>? Your question and comment are very confusing.

Comment: Solved... I had to put . before "> to specify from where to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a real HTML parser. Regular expressions are not really suitable for the job. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/766580) for more detail.

You can use [DOMDocument::loadHTML()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to parse into a structured DOM object that you can then query, like this very basic example (you need to do error checking though):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$span = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
$content = $span->item(0)->textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to:

">

define the above properly, because "> were too many in the page, so it didn't know which one to choose specficially. Therefore, it returned everything before "> until it hits (

Solution:

```
.">
```

Sample:

```
$success = preg_match('#\.">(.*?)</span>\s*\(<a id="show#s', $basicPage, $content);
```